# Spring Web Flow Action-State what should controller return?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

Spring Web Flow Action-State what should controller return?  Look at my flow below I have a action-state that based on the call to the controller i can be going to 4 diff paths..

I dont know what changes I have to make in my controller to pass back where to go.

below is my flow:

```
<action-state id="checkStatus">
        <evaluate expression="flowControllerActions.checkStatus(member)" />
        <transition on="NoSSN" to="NoSSN"/>
        <transition on="MemberExists" to="endStateMemberExists" />
        <transition on="IsDeceased" to="endStateMemberDeceased" />
        <transition on="OK" to="address" />
    </action-state>
```

and here is my method in the controller.  can someone please tell me what to do to make the tranistions work:

```
public String checkStatus(Member member) {
        LOGGER.debug("[" + member.toString() + "]");

        //
        // HOW DO I RETURN??
        //

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should be able to return String(s): "NoSSN","MemberExists","IsDeceased" and "OK" in your controller

Comment: Or you can have your method return a Java enum whose values match those strings as well.